# Proof for $x\le -1 \implies x^3-x\le 0$?

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

Here is my proof:

Let $x\in \mathbb{R}$, assume $x\le -1$

Then $x^2\ge 1$

Then $x^3\le -1$

Since $x\le -1$

$x^3\le x$

Then $x^3-x\le 0$

Therefore $x\le -1 \implies x^3-x\le 0$

Therefore $\forall$ $x\in \mathbb{R}$, $x\le -1 \implies x^3-x\le 0$

I feel the proof a bit weird and redundant, so I hope someone can fix it.

Comment: This looks okay to me, if, like you say, a bit redundant. An alternative is to factor $x^3 - x = (x + 1) x (x - 1)$. So, if $x \leq -1$, then $x^3 - x$ is a product of three nonpositive numbers and hence is nonpositive.

Comment: You only have to notice that $x^2 \ge 1$. From $x^2 \ge 1$ you can multiply both terms by $x$ and since $x$ is  negative you reverse the $\ge$ into $\le$ so you obtain $x^3\le x$ which is equivalent to $x^3-x\le 0$. END

Comment: Nice suggestion, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$x\le-1\to (x^2-1)\ge0\to x^3-x\le0$